# Android FirebaseAuth: GoogleSignInApi SignOut after credentials adquisition

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Parting from the [Android Quickstart Firebase Auth sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L143), is it ok to do the following in `onActivityResult` after a successfull Google Sign-In?

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == DialogSignInFragment.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            //-------- Is the following call allowed? --------
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);

            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogleSignInStepTwo(account);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "GOOGLE SIGN IN FAILED: " + result.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, authenticating to Firebase with a Google account is a two step process.

First you sign in into the Google account to retrieve a token, then you use that token to get the credentials so that you can perform a `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential()` call to ultimately sign into firebase.

Is it necessary for any further Firebase operation to remain signed-in with that Google Sign-In process? I'd say no, since you also don't have to remain signed into Facebook for Firebase to continue working, is this assumption correct?

Are there any negative side-effects to doing this? I want to sign out after a successfull sign-in in order to keep the code cleaner. FYI, the following code does successfully sign into Firebase even after that `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut()` call.

What are the limitations, ie, how long are those credentials valid after signing out? Long enough to be able to sign into Firebase with them, or will a race condition start on Googles servers?

Comment: If you do this you will have to make sure the user never sees the login/signIn page (while authenticated to a firebase account) or else they could sign with google account picker again, on a different account, while authenticated to another firebase account.

Comment: Before calling `FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential()` I'm calling `mFirebaseAuth.signOut()` if `mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is not `null`. Dos this solve the issue you mention? Is it possible for an app to be signed into multiple firebase accounts or what are you referring to?

Comment: I don't think you can be signed into multiple firbease accounts. All im saying is that when you signOut of the GoogleApiClient it will expose the GoogleSelectYourAccount dialog again if you click the GoogleLoginButton, and that could cause problems if you are still authenticated to a firebase account. So just make sure you take measures to prevent a user from seeing that button when he is still authenticated with firebase :)